# Cells are only deleted/added once leaving and returning

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I don't think it's necessary to post my code for this issue. I am just looking for an explanation or probably one line of code to solve my problem. When I delete or add a cellForRowAtIndexPath within my app, it is both added or deleted to Parse, but does not appear in the app until segueing to a different screen and returning. I have tried moving my delete and add codes into ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        var object: PFObject = self.items[indexPath.row] as PFObject
        let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Item deleted from cart!", message: "", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss")
        alert.show()

        object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to show code. Show relevant code where you attempt to add or delete a row.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Comment: You never update `self.items`. You need to remove the object from the array in addition to removing the object from Parse.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting the item from Parse, but you are not deleting the item from your `self.items` array, which is probably the data source to your table view.  The `self.items` array is probably initialized in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method from Parse, which is why you're seeing it update when you come back to the screen.  Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

try `tableView.reloadData()`

You need to call that method for iOS to look again at your data source and render the tableView.

Comment: Calling `reloadData` is overkill if you just add/remove a row or two.

Comment: Perhaps: self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(modifiedRows as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

Comment: I added my code, let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
        items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

Had to add this line above the object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        var object: PFObject = self.items[indexPath.row] as PFObject
        let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Item deleted from cart!", message: "", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss")
        alert.show()

        object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in

        self.items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
    }
}
```